# Get 12hrs time in ascending order using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, time, sql-order-by

I have to get records based on time in ascending  order but it is retrieving data like 01:pm than 09:am and last 11:00 am here time stored in column is 12 hrs format and column structure is varcha but for reason I cant change it to mysql time ,so how to get time in ascending order according to am pm

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(time_slot,'%h.%i%p')

current output:
01:00 pm
09:00 am
11:00 am


Expected output:

09:00 am
11:00 am
01:00 pm
```

Comment: Things may be immeasurably improved by switching to proper data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your format description, that does not match the input string: it has the wrong separator (`.` instead of `:`). As a result, your conversion returns `null`, and no sorting actually happens, resulting in records being rendered in an *undefined* order.

You can easily check this with the following statement, which returns `null`:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01:00 pm','%h.%i%p')
```

I think that you want:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(time_slot,'%h:%i %p')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below sql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(timeField,'%h:%i %p');
```